# Create a line with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3, and I want to use the xy coordinates in lineData to create a series of lines that are connected to each other. When I run this code, I don't get any errors but nothing shows up either. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I know that this would work if I were to use JSON, but I'm trying to apply D3 to something that just has an array of data like below, so I want to avoid that.

```
// x, y, x, y, ... etc.
var lineData = [1, 5, 20, 20, 40, 10, 60, 40, 80, 5, 100, 60];

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200);

var x = 0;

while (x < 11) {
    var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
        .x(lineData[x])
        .y(lineData[x + 1])
        .interpolate("linear");

    var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
        .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");

    x++;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do -- the way you have it set up at the moment, only a single point will be drawn per iteration.

Comment: I want to draw a line from lineData[0] to lineData[1], from lineData[1] to lineData[2], etc.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.janwillemtulp.com/2011/04/01/tutorial-line-chart-in-d3/) describes how to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I want to draw a line from (lineData[0], lineData[1]) to (lineData[2], lineData[3]). Thanks for the tutorial.

Comment: I would reformat the data for this to separate out x and y values. That will make it much easier to draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to plot the values in `lineData` on the y-axis, with a standard step (eg 10) on the x-axis, you can do this:

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return (i * 10); })
    .y(function(d) { return d; })
    .interpolate("linear");

svgContainer.append("svg:path").attr("d", lineFunction(lineData));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/4e2rkm5d/

The key thing to know is that through `lineFunction(lineData)`, you are calling `lineFunction`for each point in your data array: no need to loop through it manually with d3

### Update

Alternatively if you want `lineData` to be interpreted as `[x1,y1,x2,y2...]`, then you should first modify the data (as per Lars's supggestion), something like this:

```
var formattedLineData = [];

function formatDataPoints(element, index, array) {
    // For every even index (0, 2, 4...)
    if (index % 2 === 0){
        // ...take the current value in the array, and the next one
        formattedLineData.push({"x": array[index], "y": array[index + 1]});
    }
}
lineData.forEach(formatDataPoints);
```

This will create an array of objects that looks like this:

[image: capture of console view]

Then change the line function to expect this format:

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return (height - d.y); })
    .interpolate("linear");
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/4e2rkm5d/1/

Note - we do `height - d.y` because in SVG, (0,0) is in the top-left, whereas I assume you want to count the y-axis from the bottom